# Смерть событий после выполнения ajax

Tags: jquery, события, ajax, javascript

В JS написан обработчик кнопки `*удалить сообщение*` (миничат).
После обновления сообщений (вместе с кнопками) через ajax обработчик перестает работать.

Как решить проблему?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сделайте делегированную обработку событий:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete-msg-btn', function(e){
  /* code*/
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю два варианта

1. После AJAX вешать обработчики на новые кнопки.
2. Повесить один обработчик на родительский элемент, содержащий все сообщения с этими кнопками и проверять e.target. Если таргет является кнопкой, то выполнять нужную функцию. Определить, кнопка это или нет можно, например, по наличию класса(допустим, .button).

Answer (score 0):

`onClick` уже не котируется? Делаем функцию, и вставляем в `onClick` и будет работать при любых условиях.